# D3 chart zooms the plot but not the axis - callback.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, zooming

I've got a chart based on this [tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@ahmedhammeda/how-to-create-a-zoomable-and-animated-bar-chart-with-d3-js)

It's working very all apart from that when I zoom, the plot works but not the x-axis.
The problem lies on my zoom function

```
const zoomed = (event) => {
      xScale.range(
        [margin.left, width - margin.right].map((d) =>
          event.transform.applyX(d)
        )
      );

      svg
        .selectAll(".bars rect")
        .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.name))
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth());

      svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
    };
```

The last line `svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);` throws the error: `callback.apply is not a function`.

if I log `svg.selectAll(".x-axis")` to the console I get the corresponding nodes with the `call` method attached so I don't know why's not working. I'm using d3 7.6.1 so this method might not work in the same way but after researching, I couldn't find an answer.

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-mclean-svz3zb?file=/src/ZoomChart.js:3444-3481)

Comment: The first parameter of the call function is the function you want to call on your selection. xAxis is not a function, it is a d3 selection.

Comment: That's helpful to understand thanks but there are numerous examples where this kind of approach works (eg https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/431a331294d2b5ddd33f947cf4c81319). changing my `xAxis` to a function doesn't help

Comment: In the example you give, xAxis is an axis generator created by d3.axisBottom() which is again a function callable on a selection. Are you sure you are in the same cinfiguration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you zoom, you want to recreate the x scale inside the ***g.x-axis*** element. To do that you need to call an axis generator on that element like that:

```
axisGenerator(d3.selectAll(".x-axis"))
```

which is equivalent to execute:

```
d3.selectAll(".x-axis").call(axisGenerator)
```

In your code the parameter to call() is not an axis generator. The ***xAxis*** variable is a d3 selection. So you first need to create an axis generator:

```
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0);
```

And then initialize the x axis by creating a group element and call the axis generator on it:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
   .attr("class", "x-axis")
   .call(xAxis)
```

In your ***zoomed*** function, you can then update the x axis like that:

```
svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
```